# Add a button to the right side of Element UI's Tabs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I am using the [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation) component library for Vue 2. Element has a **[Tabs](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tabs)** component as shown in the following screenshot (blue rectangle):

[image]

I want to add a button to where the red arrow is pointing. But the **Tabs** component doesn't have a native way to add an accessory UI component like that, such as by using a slot. Since this area is within the Tabs component, I don't see a way to insert an accessory component in that area.

If you look at the inspector, I basically have to insert a **Button** component after the `div` with the class `tablist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this programatically:

1. Style the nav bar in `el-tabs` to set `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-between`:

   ```css
   .el-tabs__nav-scroll {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
   }
   ```
2. Add an `el-button` to the template, and give it a template ref (named `btn`).

   ```html
   <el-button ref="btn">Click me!</el-button>
   ```
3. Apply a template ref to the `el-tabs` component (named `tabs`).

   ```html
   <el-tabs ref="tabs">
   ```
4. In the `mounted()` hook, insert the `el-button` into `el-tabs`:

   ```js
   export default {
     mounted() {
       const scrollBar = this.$refs.tabs.$el.querySelector('.el-tabs__nav-scroll')
       scrollBar.appendChild(this.$refs.btn.$el)
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abJMmKm)

Answer (score 0):

I used the slot, the create button is obtained on the left.

```
<el-tabs>
    <el-tab-pane
      name="ExTab"
      ref="ExTab"
    >
    ExTab
    </el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane
      name="add"
      ref="add"
    >
          <span slot="label" >
            <el-button
              slot="reference"
              type="primary"
              round
              icon="el-icon-plus"
              style="margin: 0 1% 0 1% "
              @click.stop="addTab()"
            />
        </span>
    </el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, answered question, please explain how it complements the other answer.